# How long should it take to export data to your drive?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-drive

I'm new to GEE and I'm using their test script to send an image to my drive:

```
// Load a landsat image and select three bands.
var landsat = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_123032_20140515')
    .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([116.2621, 39.8412, 116.4849, 40.01236]);

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: landsat,
    description: 'imageToDriveExample',
    scale: 30,
    region: geometry
});
```

My first attempt ran for 20 minutes with never fully downloading.  The second attempt crashed after about 20 seconds and kicked out a `earth engine exceeded memory capacity` error.  I'm currently running it again, but so far it's almost 20 minutes again.

Can some one tell me how long on average it should take, and if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What spec is your hardware, what is the capacity of your network

Comment: @nmtoken Im on an Acer core i7, 1.8GHz, with 12 GB DDR4.  I'm in the library so I'm  not sure of the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added  `var image = landsat.clip(geometry)` before the export and set

`Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'imageToDriveExample',
    scale: 30,
    region: geometry
});`

and it took 24 seconds to export to my drive. I think this is taking so long because you are querying the whole Landsat image instead of just the smaller portion, but I am not certain how the back end of GEE works in this case.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked very well.  What I'm trying to do is find images of the coastline, do geometrical analysis on them, and then keep a copy of the image with the computed data.  I've been search the internet for about two weeks now, but I'm not really finding anything that describes how to do this.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I do not have a code that would work for that at the moment. You should ask this as a separate question and include whatever code you have managed to create for your project